# Create object of custom UIView subclass programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have written a simple `UIView` subclass (code below) to display a gift message preview which will then be rendered into a PDF.

I was able to set it as the custom class for a `UIView` in Interface Builder but I also want to create an instance in code. I tried to do this like so:

```
let v2 = GiftMessageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: A6.height, height: A6.width))
v2.textView.text = (orderDetials["giftMessage"] as! String)
```

However, when I loaded the generated PDF it was blank and I am sure it is not a problem with the PDF rendering as is works when generating it from the instance in Interface Builder. Thus I am assuming it's a problem with the subclass and/or the code I have used to instantiate it.

**Subclass code (note - uses SnapKit and SwifterSwift pods):**

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import SwifterSwift

class GiftMessageView: UIView {

    /// A5 Paper Size
    private let A5 = CGSize(width: 420.0, height: 595.0)
    ///A6 Paper Size
    private let A6 = CGSize(width: 298.0, height: 420.0)

    let textView = UILabel()
    let logoView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {


        logoView.image = UIImage(named: "surprises_dark_pdf")
        logoView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        textView.text = "[ YOUR MESSAGE GOES HERE ]\n\n\n[ LEAVE YOUR NAME OR BE ANONAMOUS ]"
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.numberOfLines = 20
        textView.font = textView.font.withSize(12)


        self.addSubviews([logoView, textView])

        let margin = self.height/20

        logoView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(self.width/2)
            make.height.equalTo(self.height/4)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self)
            make.top.equalTo(self).offset(margin)
        }

        textView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(logoView.snp.bottom).offset(margin/10)
            make.left.equalTo(self).offset(margin)
            make.right.equalTo(self).offset(-margin)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self).offset(-margin)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use your debugger. What is actually happening inside your `GiftMessageView` class? Hint: none of the important code is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the code to a function

```
class GiftMessageView: UIView {

    /// A5 Paper Size
    private let A5 = CGSize(width: 420.0, height: 595.0)
    ///A6 Paper Size
    private let A6 = CGSize(width: 298.0, height: 420.0)

    let textView = UILabel()
    let logoView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        shared()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        shared()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        // not called until it's in xib/ib

    }

    func shared(){

        logoView.image = UIImage(named: "surprises_dark_pdf")
        logoView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        textView.text = "[ YOUR MESSAGE GOES HERE ]\n\n\n[ LEAVE YOUR NAME OR BE ANONAMOUS ]"
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.numberOfLines = 20
        textView.font = textView.font.withSize(12)


        self.addSubviews([logoView, textView])

        let margin = self.height/20

        logoView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(self.width/2)
            make.height.equalTo(self.height/4)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self)
            make.top.equalTo(self).offset(margin)
        }

        textView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(logoView.snp.bottom).offset(margin/10)
            make.left.equalTo(self).offset(margin)
            make.right.equalTo(self).offset(-margin)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self).offset(-margin)
        }
    }

}
```